# Qt QML How to change size of a component and get the whole page change

Tags: qt, qml

I am working on an android application and I am facing a problem. In a page of the application I have some input fields, one of them is for date and I wanted to add a Calendar that open on demand for selecting the date or just enter the date manually, for this, I created a custom component which is composed of a TextInput and a button which when clicked will create the calendar item with a loader and set the size of the loader to 80 (it was 0 initially) all this components are included in a columnlayout. When the button get clicked the calendar is drawn below the other input fields.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

FocusScope {
    id: root
    Layout.preferredHeight: 20
    property alias text: input.text
    property alias border: background.border
    property alias backgroundColor: background.color
    property alias textColor: input.color

    ColumnLayout{
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 1
    RowLayout{
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Rectangle {
            id: background
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "darkgrey"
            TextInput {
                id: input
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 3
                verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
                focus: true
                text: dateInput.selectedDate
            }
        }
        CustomButton {
            id: calandar
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 40
            image: "icons/CalandarButton.svg"
            onClicked: {
                console.log("clicked calandar")
                if(calendarLoader.status === Loader.Null){
                    calendarLoader.height = 80
                    calendarLoader.sourceComponent =               Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.5; import QtQuick.Controls 1.4; Calendar {}",
                                                                        calendarLoader,
                                                                        "calandarpp")
                }
                else{
                    calendarLoader.height = 0
                    calendarLoader.sourceComponent = undefined
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Loader {
        id: calendarLoader
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 0
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is below, then try changing its `z` coordinate.

There is no need to do `Qt.createQmlObject()` ever. It's enough to toggle `Loader.active` or `Item.visible`.

Example is not reproducible, make sure that it runs by itself with `qmlscene`.

This works for me:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

FocusScope {
    id: root
    Layout.preferredHeight: 20
    property alias text: input.text
    property alias border: background.border
    property alias backgroundColor: background.color
    property alias textColor: input.color

    z: 1

    Loader {
        id: calendarLoader
        active: false
        sourceComponent: Calendar {}
        z: 1
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 1
        RowLayout{
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            Rectangle {
                id: background
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                color: "darkgrey"
                TextInput {
                    id: input
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 3
                    verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
                    focus: true
                }
            }

            Button {
                id: calandar
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 40
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked calandar")
                    calendarLoader.active = !calendarLoader.active
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the z coordinate thing, but I am always getting the calendar under everything else. I had just read about loader.active thing and I am using it now. the page of my application contain other input fields this component is one of others and when I put Loader to active the calendar draw under the other inputs fields not this one.

Comment: The example gives error: `Error: Cannot assign QObject* to QQmlComponent` when launched as `qmlscene example.qml` and clicking on the button.

Comment: On my machine it works http://imgur.com/a/uwNIU here a capture of the page with the calendar active, you will see how the calendar is above the date input filed and below the other fields

Comment: It's a problem with the `ColumnLayout`. The calendar is a member of the `ColumnLayout`, but its `height` is set to 0. Try `Layout.fillHeight: true` - then it would push other fields down. But if you want a free-floating calendar, then move its `Loader` into the root item, and then set the x/y/z coordinates of the `Loader` to the absolute coordinates of the field to which you want to glue the calendar.

Comment: Same problem I changed the position of the calendar to get a floating one but the calendar is always under all the other fields except the parent one.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I tryed your example but i still get the calendar under the description input fields, i will upload my app code in github like this u can execute the hole code.

Comment: https://github.com/houssemDevs/cn this is the app code. On the first page click on the '+' in the app header you will reach the page where the calendar is and try to open it up

Comment: Added more `z` to my example, now it works when included into other file.

Comment: I put z to 100 but still don't work I guess I will just drop the calendar till I get more experience with this whole qml things. Thank you for your help

Comment: No, I meant you set `z` for the whole `FocusScope` to bring it forward. It works with your project.